# Delphi 2007 and Dynamic Variant Array as Var Parameter

Tags: arrays, delphi, variant

I have a form which allows a use to select a record and this form then returns the ID of the record and an arbitrary number of fields values that the calling form may need.  To do this, I have a function which handles creating the select form and passes all the values to and from the calling form:

```
Function Execute(AOwner: TComponent; AConnection: TADOConnection;
  AEditor: String; AButtons: TViewButtons; Var AID: Integer;
  Var ARtnVals: Array of Variant): TModalResult;
Var
  I: Integer;
Begin
  frmSelectGrid := TfrmSelectGrid.Create(AOwner);
  Try
    With frmSelectGrid Do
    Begin
      Connection := AConnection;
      Editor := AEditor;
      Buttons := AButtons;
      ID := AID;

      Result := ShowModal;
      If Result = mrOK Then
      Begin
        AID := ID;
        //VarArrayRedim(ARtnVals, Length(RtnVals));  !! Won't compile
        //SetLength(ARtnVals, Length(RtnVals));      !! Won't compile either
        For I := 0 To High(RtnVals) Do
          ARtnVals[I] := RtnVals[I];                 // Causes runtime exception
      End;
    End;
  Finally
    FreeAndNil(frmSelectGrid);
  End;
End;
```

The selector form has the following public properties:

```
public
  Connection: TADOConnection;
  Editor: String;
  Buttons: TViewButtons;
  ID: Integer;
  RtnVals: Array of Variant;
end;
```

And in the OK click, I have the following code:

```
Var
  I, Idx, C: Integer;


  // Count how many fields are being returned
  C := 0;
  For I := 0 To Config.Fields.Count - 1 Do
    If Config.Fields[I].Returned Then
      Inc(C);

  // If no fields to be returned, then just exit.
  If C = 0 Then
    Exit;

  // Set the size of the RtnVals and assign the field values to the array.
  SetLength(RtnVals, C);
  Idx := 0;
  For I := 0 To Config.Fields.Count - 1 Do
    If Config.Fields[I].Returned Then
    Begin
      RtnVals[Idx] := aqItems.FieldByName(Config.Fields[I].FieldName).Value;
      Inc(Idx);
    End;
```

So, once the user clicks OK to select a record, the RtnVals array is populated with the field values of the fields to be returned.  I now need to copy these values to ARtnVals in the Execute function so that they are returned to the calling form.

My question is how do I set the size of the ARtnVals array so that I can copy the fields?  SetLength doesn't work like it does in the OK click function above.  VarArrayRedim doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When written in a procedure parameter list, this code

```
Var ARtnVals: Array of Variant
```

is an **open array**, and not a **dynamic array**. An open array cannot be resized. An open array is no use to you here.

Instead define a type for the array:

```
type
  TDynamicArrayOfVariant = array of Variant;
```

Use that type for your parameter, which is actually best as an out parameter:

```
function Execute(..., out RtnVals: TDynamicArrayOfVariant): TModalResult;
```

And then pass the function a `TDynamicArrayOfVariant` to be populated.

Now you have a dynamic array rather than an open array in `Execute`, and you can use `SetLength` to size it.